# How to reset Debug setting in vs code studio

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

while debugging my application on vs studio code I accidentally hit the `debug packages +sdk` options that pops up at the bottom right, Now even if I run my application it will throw me unwanted errors like `<asynchronous suspension>` from the package I imported. How can I get back my default Debug settings?
What I have tried, is reset vs studio code by removing all lines of code except `{}` from `settings.json` but it didn't work, The same program runs fine in android studio.
Any help please ?

Comment: You should be able to keep hitting that button to cycle through the options. It only shows up during a debug session, so try starting the debugger, then when the button shows up, just click on it until it says only "Debug my code"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

towards the bottom left, there is an option to build in various mode, had to change it until I found out the right one that was working for me, i.e `debug my code`
[image: Had to change the options here to debug my code]